# I am not getting the file input parameters in a php script

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to upload some images with a PHP script. In my HTML page I've made a `<form>` to load the files this way :

```
<form action="{{ path("uploader_photos") }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file"  id="file"  name="files" style="display: none" multiple/>
<button type="submit" form="pic_add" >Download</button>
```

And this is the controller method where i should get the `$_POST` elements :

```
public function uploaderAction(){

    $mail = $_SESSION['mail'];
    $pass = $_SESSION['password'];
    $oauth = new OAuth($mail, $pass);

    $baseUrl = "http://api.localhost/v1/";

    $url = "{$baseUrl}upload/" . $mail . '/photosup';
    $oauth->fetch($url, $_REQUEST, OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_POST);

    $reponseInformations = json_decode($oauth->getLastResponse(), true);
    if (!$_POST) {
        return new Response(json_encode(array('erreur' => $reponseInformations['erreur'])), 500, array('Content-Type' => 'application/json'));
    }

    //return $this->redirect('photos');
}
```

The issue that i'm always gettin an empty `$_POST` variable, i'm making sure to passe the parameters in the post request like in the image  :
[image]

So any one to help please !

`$_FILES` **var_dump :**

```
 array (size=1)
 'files' => 
   array (size=5)
  'name' => string 'Falling iron man.jpg' (length=20)
  'type' => string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
  'tmp_name' => string '/tmp/phpn5wWfK' (length=14)
  'error' => int 0
  'size' => int 507102
```

Comment: Uploaded files are in `$_FILES`, not `$_POST`.

Comment: I'm not getting any one of those $_POST, $_FILES or $_REQUEST !

Comment: The form doesn't have any other inputs.

Comment: Wich means ? i didn't get you

Comment: @Barmar i'm getting exactly a `$_FILES['files']['error']`

Comment: Can you show the output of `var_dump($_FILES)` in the question?

Comment: what happens if you do `<form action='{{ path("uploader_photos") }}'`, note the single and double quotes, I know the action will have changed but if you have double quotes in there it won't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use a `multiple` input, you need to give it a name ending in `[]`, so that PHP will collect all the inputs into an array.

```
<input type="file"  id="file"  name="files[]" style="display: none" multiple/>
```

Then you can access `$_FILES['files']['name'][0]` for the first uploaded file, `$_FILES['files']['name'][1]` for the second file, and so on.

See http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php